# How to save slash("/") value to Javascript object, for mongodb $in/$nin query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, slash

I wanna add /something/ value to Javascript object, not "/something/" value.

```
var x = {
 "age" : "11",
 "lastName" : {
     $nin : [/Jo/,/Ka/]
  }
}

function foo(){
  ...

  x["lastName"].$nin.push(...)
}
```

MongoDB Query:
db.collectionName.find({x})

$in, $nin Query is working only with /.../ value.

Comment: Can you explain your problem little bit more?

Comment: Is the confusion over `/regex/` vs. `"/string with slashes/"`?